# Rollbar People tracking Angular 7

Tags: angular, rollbar

I would like to get advantage of the people tracking feature for my rollbar Angular 7 integration.
In the doc I found this [DOC](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/person-tracking) but I don't understand what/where I have to do to add this 'person property' to my error reporting.

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Once user is authenticated you can reconfigure Rollbar with the user data.

```
constructor(@Inject(RollbarService) private rollbar: Rollbar ...);

rollbarTrack(user) {
    this.rollbar.configure({
      //what you had here before
      payload: {
      //what you had here before
        person: {
          id: user.id //required
          username: user.username
          email: user.emial
        }
      }
    });
}
```

call the rollbarTrack(user) where/when you handle user login